# Sections and rows count NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've got an `NSFetchedResultsController`, which I have confirmed that their is data being saved into it whenever the user creates a new object. However, I have found that the only thing not updating still is the sections and rows count of the `NSFetchedResultsController`. I'm not sure why that is.

I've tried variating the creation of the new object many different ways. I've also tried logging every step of the process to try and see what's going on, but there really isn't much I can log for something like this, so I'm now left with little to no information on why this is happening. Anyways, here is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"number of sections: %d", [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count]);
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"number of rows: %d", [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects]);
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
}

- (void)saveForName:(NSString *)name
              photo:(NSData *)photo
         timePosted:(NSDate *)timePosted
            details:(NSString *)details
        dateAndTime:(NSDate *)dateTime
           location:(NSString *)location
{

    if (!self.shindysDatabase) {
        NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
        self.shindysDatabase = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
        NSLog(@"shindy database reset.");
    }

    Shindy *shindy = (Shindy *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Shindy" inManagedObjectContext:self.shindysDatabase.managedObjectContext];

    shindy.name = name;
    shindy.photo = photo;
    shindy.timePosted = timePosted;
    shindy.details = details;
    shindy.dateAndTime = dateTime;
    shindy.location = location;

    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.shindysDatabase.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    Shindy *shindy = (Shindy *)[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Shindy" inManagedObjectContext:self.shindysDatabase.managedObjectContext];
    shindy = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *avatar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 64, 56)];
    // Converting NSData to UIImage
    avatar.image = shindy.photo;
    avatar.clipsToBounds = NO;
    [cell addSubview:avatar];

    NSLog(@"avatar: %@", avatar);

    // The name of the user who posted the shindy
    UILabel *avatarName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 10, 125, 19)];
    avatarName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    avatarName.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    avatarName.text = shindy.name;
    [cell addSubview:avatarName];

    NSLog(@"avatarName: %@", avatarName);

    // The time the shindy was posted
    NSDateFormatter *timePostedFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timePostedFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm"];
    UILabel *timePosted = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(280, 10, 30, 20)];
    timePosted.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    timePosted.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    timePosted.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    timePosted.text = [timePostedFormatter stringFromDate:shindy.timePosted];
    [cell addSubview:timePosted];

    NSLog(@"Time posted: %@", timePosted);

    // Formatting fetched NSDate into string
    NSDateFormatter *dateAndTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timePostedFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm"];
    UILabel *dateAndTimeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 70, 30, 20)];
    dateAndTimeLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    dateAndTimeLabel.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    dateAndTimeLabel.text = [dateAndTimeFormatter stringFromDate:shindy.dateAndTime];
    [cell addSubview:dateAndTimeLabel];

    NSLog(@"date and time: %@", dateAndTimeLabel.text);

    // Details of the Shindy
    UILabel *shindyDescription = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 20, 220 , 50)];
    shindyDescription.numberOfLines = 3;
    shindyDescription.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    shindyDescription.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    shindyDescription.text = shindy.details;
    [cell addSubview:shindyDescription];

    NSLog(@"details: %@", shindyDescription.text);

    return cell;
}
```

**BoilerPlate Code:**

This is just the code that I have to do the updating when an object is changed.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
                                               arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't work with NSFetchedResultController in a long time, but at first sight I would say :
`Where are you asking your table view to update itself?`
I don't think that the result controller will trigger the table update itself.

---

I was just in the [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation and I've also seen this :

> In addition, fetched results controllers provide the following features:
>   Optionally monitor changes to objects in the associated managed object
>   context, and report changes in the results set to its delegate (see
>   “The Controller’s Delegate”).

And also in the [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate) documentation

> you could just implement controllerDidChangeContent: (which is sent to
>   the delegate when all pending changes have been processed) to reload
>   the table view.

---

Just for Debugging purpose, have you try to remove :

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller 
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
```

And just do :

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I'm not saying this is a solution, but it would be interesting to see if the result is the same.

Comment: I have setup all of those things already in my code elsewhere. That code is kind of considered a "default", so I didn't bother posting it.

Comment: You would be surprise to see how much mistake are made into "default" code

Comment: It's copied and pasted from Apple Documentation. But I see you really want to see it, so I've edited my question to show it as well :)

Comment: Your NSFetchResultsControllerDelegate methods takes care of the updating part from controllerWillChangeContent: to controllerDidChangeContent:. reloadData: from UITableView is not necessary, if you have beginUpdates: and endUpdates:.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the sectionNameKeyPath when you create your NSFetchedResultsController object? If you use nil, only one section will be created.

> (instancetype)initWithFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context sectionNameKeyPath:(NSString *)sectionNameKeyPath cacheName:(NSString *)name;
>
> sectionNameKeyPath:
> A key path on result objects that returns the section name. Pass nil to indicate that the controller should generate a single section.